# Network adapter not recognised

Tags: windows-7, drivers, motherboard, network-adapter

I've had to re-format my PC and installed Win 7 Pro.

Got everything installed but Network Adapter not being recognised so I've got no internet. I don't have the motherboard driver CD so I attempted to download the drivers from website  and copy them over a USB and install them but it still didn't recognise it.

The motherboard is Asus H81M.

I downloaded the drivers from: http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H81MPLUS/HelpDesk_Download/

No luck, any ideas how to solve this issue without the motherboard CD?

Thanks

Comment: What actually happened when you tried to install them? Any error messages?  What bit-level of Windows 7 are you using (32 or 64), and specifically which driver did you use from Asus' site?

Comment: It's 64bit. The installaion was fine, it just didn't fix the issue. The Network adapter just isn't coming up and when I try to resolve it from Network and Sharing Center, it says there is missing drivers. The ones I installed are: Realtek LAN Driver V7.85.425.2014 and Realtek Ethernet Utility V2.0.2.7 for Windows Win7 64bit

Comment: When you look in the Device Manager, does the network adapter show up under Unknown Devices?

Comment: Yes, it does appear there.

Comment: Unzip the driver you downloaded.  Head to the device in Device Manager. Properties -> Driver -> Update Driver -> "Browse my computer for driver".   When it asks where to get the drivers from, specify that it look in the "Realtek_LAN_V7854252014_Win7_V8314232014_Win8\Win7\WIN7\64" folder you unzipped.  Then come back and let us know what happened.

Comment: Are you certain you have the correct drivers for your motherboard? You linked to drivers for an H81M-PLUS though only mentioned you have an H81M, but Asus has lots of H81M* boards and no plain "H81M" as far as I can see (http://www.asus.com/support/Product-Search/?keyword=h81m). A lot of those have different NICs so possibly the H81M-PLUS drivers are not the correct ones for you. If you're not certain, you should be able to identify the motherboard model with a utility like CPU-Z (http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html). Posted as an answer 'cause I don't have rep to comment.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I did try that, it just says "Windows could not find the driver software for your device".

Comment: @R4mzy You were right, I had the wrong motherboard driver all along! Thanks :)